# Split a string into 2 parts in batch

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, batch-file, split

I want to split the name of each folder (in a `for` loop) into 2 parts : the left part (before the delimiter " - ") and the right part (after the delimiter).

Example : "Bonjour - Cher ami"    =>     left=Bonjour,   right=Cher Ami

But it doesn't work :

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (
  set "fname=%%a" 
  set "right=%fname:* - =%" 
  call set "left=%%fname: - %right%=%%" 
  echo [%left%] * [%right%]
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to read folder names and split the names and print them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a code block you need an other syntax:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    set "fname=%%~a"
    call set "right=%%fname:* - =%%" 
    call call set "left=%%%%fname: - %%right%%=%%%%"
    call echo [%%left%%] * [%%right%%]
)
```

If there is no "`-`" in the folder name, then %left%==%right%.

Comment: Thanks!
It works now, except that if `%%a = blabla - hehe`, then `left=blablahehe`   `right=hehe`,  instead of `left=blabla` `right=hehe`

Comment: Yes, you are right, code needs more `%%`. Will make an (hopefully last) edit :)